# Simulate ROW_NUMBER, RANK and DENSE_RANK with subquery

Tags: sql, firebird, self-join, firebird2.5

I wanted to use `DENSE_RANK()` function on one of my JasperReport query but it's not available for Firebird 2.5. But there is an [example on the firebirdfaq.org site](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq343/) to simulate this function using aggregate functions and context variables or generators. i.e

```
SELECT p.name, p.score, COUNT(DISTINCT others.score) + 1 AS "dense_rank"
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN players others ON others.score > p.score
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY "dense_rank"
```

So it's a self join on players.

My problem is I don't have a defined table like 'players' to self join it with but my query using two tables. I tried creating an alias and using subquery to self join but no success.

```
SELECT  x.DateCompleted, x.TimeCompleted, x.numOfBatches, COUNT(DISTINCT others.DateCompleted) + 1 AS "dense_rank"
FROM 
     (SELECT  floor(PRODUCEDH.COMPLETE_TIME)+cast('30.12.1899' AS TIMESTAMP) AS DateCompleted,
              (ABS(PRODUCEDH.COMPLETE_TIME) - FLOOR(ABS(PRODUCEDH.COMPLETE_TIME)))+cast('30.12.1899' AS TIMESTAMP) AS TimeCompleted,
              COMMODITIES.CODE,
              COMMODITIES.NAME AS COMMODITY_NAME,
              (SUM(PRODUCEDH.MIXSIZE) / 100) as numOfBatches
        FROM  
              "PRODUCEDH" "PRODUCEDH",
              "COMMODITIES" "COMMODITIES"
        WHERE
                PRODUCEDH."COMMODITYID" = COMMODITIES."COMMODITYID"
                AND ((PRODUCEDH."STATUS" IN ('C','X')))
                AND PRODUCEDH.COMPLETE_TIME IS NOT NULL
                AND COALESCE(PRODUCEDH."COMPLETE_TIME",PRODUCEDH."CREATETIME")+CAST('30.12.1899'AS TIMESTAMP) >= '05-01-2018'
                AND COALESCE(PRODUCEDH."COMPLETE_TIME",PRODUCEDH."CREATETIME")+CAST('30.12.1899'AS TIMESTAMP) <= '06-13-2018'
        GROUP BY
                DateCompleted,
                TimeCompleted,
                COMMODITIES.code,
                COMMODITIES.NAME
        ORDER BY
                DateCompleted,
                TimeCompleted
                ASC
        ) x
LEFT JOIN  x others ON others.DateCompleted > x.DateCompleted  <------ Error points here
GROUP BY x.DateCompleted, x.TimeCompleted
ORDER BY "dense_rank"
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but it fails to pick on the table "X" and throws a error i.e  `SQL error code = -204 Table unknown X`

Comment: I think you have to repeat the subquery in Firebird.  In most SQL dialects, you would use a *common table expression* (CTE), but I don't think Firebird supports them.

Comment: There is nothing "official" about firebirdfaq.org. The official implementation of these is Firebird 3 which added support for [window functions](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html), consider upgrading.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Firebird supports common table expressions, see [Common Table Expressions (“WITH ... AS ... SELECT”)](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-select.html#fblangref25-dml-select-cte)  in the Firebird 2.5 language reference

Comment: @GordonLinoff It works with repeating the subquery like u suggested. but its taking quite a while to complete the execution. like if my query taking 0.311 sec , it takes around 3 mins if i simulate it. Any chance if i could make it quick ?

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be to upgrade to Firebird 3, as that as built-in support for [window functions like `DENSE_RANK()`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs).

In any case, the problem with your query is that you can't define a table `x` based on a sub-query in the left hand side of a join, and then use that `x` as well on the right hand. Instead you need to use a [Common Table Expression](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select-cte), which where introduced in Firebird 2.1:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT  floor(PRODUCEDH.COMPLETE_TIME)+cast('30.12.1899' AS TIMESTAMP) AS DateCompleted,
          (ABS(PRODUCEDH.COMPLETE_TIME) - FLOOR(ABS(PRODUCEDH.COMPLETE_TIME)))+cast('30.12.1899' AS TIMESTAMP) AS TimeCompleted,
          COMMODITIES.CODE,
          COMMODITIES.NAME AS COMMODITY_NAME,
          (SUM(PRODUCEDH.MIXSIZE) / 100) as numOfBatches
    FROM  
          "PRODUCEDH" "PRODUCEDH",
          "COMMODITIES" "COMMODITIES"
    WHERE
            PRODUCEDH."COMMODITYID" = COMMODITIES."COMMODITYID"
            AND ((PRODUCEDH."STATUS" IN ('C','X')))
            AND PRODUCEDH.COMPLETE_TIME IS NOT NULL
            AND COALESCE(PRODUCEDH."COMPLETE_TIME",PRODUCEDH."CREATETIME")+CAST('30.12.1899'AS TIMESTAMP) >= '05-01-2018'
            AND COALESCE(PRODUCEDH."COMPLETE_TIME",PRODUCEDH."CREATETIME")+CAST('30.12.1899'AS TIMESTAMP) <= '06-13-2018'
    GROUP BY
            DateCompleted,
            TimeCompleted,
            COMMODITIES.code,
            COMMODITIES.NAME
    ORDER BY
            DateCompleted,
            TimeCompleted
            ASC
    )
SELECT  x.DateCompleted, x.TimeCompleted, x.numOfBatches, COUNT(DISTINCT others.DateCompleted) + 1 AS "dense_rank"
FROM x
LEFT JOIN x others ON others.DateCompleted > x.DateCompleted
GROUP BY x.DateCompleted, x.TimeCompleted
ORDER BY "dense_rank"
```

One word of warning: I haven't checked if this solution itself is correct; it just addresses the problem of trying to reference `x` twice.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I've tried your solution aswell and it worked but m struggling with the execution time.
For set conditions if query takes 0.311s on its own, by simulating this function it is taking around 3 mins. Is there anyway I could optimise the execution ?   
I know it would be best to upgrade to firebird 3 but its not possible for me right now.

Comment: @AlphaTry I can't think of something straight away. This is simply not very efficient because of the self-join.